# Easiest way to read in fields from a line

Tags: c++

I'm working on reading in lines from a file. Each line follows this exact format, with a `|` delimiter:

```
4|Get Shorty (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Get%20Shorty%20(1995)|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

I'm using `ifstream` and `getline` to grab each line from the file. What would be the best way to grab all fields on a single line with n delimiters? Can this be done with string streams? I can rig something up using `find` and `substr`, but it would get ugly pretty fast, and I don't think it would be able to take into account a line with a variable n amount of delimiters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can initialise a `std::istringstream` with the line, and then read out the fields with `getline(isstream, field, '|')`. Put the call in a loop to read fields until the stream fails:

```
std::istringstream isstream(line);
for (std::string s; getline(isstream, s, '|');)
  // do stuff with s
```

Comment: please complete your answer with the full code example. It will be clear that way.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that third option on `getline`!

Comment: @Bob, `std::getline` gets a line, however `std::istream::getline` gets a partial line (despite its name!)